# The variable is not incremental after click the "Next" button using C# with asp.net web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-applications

I am trying to filter records from database and show them on `textfields` one by one by clicking the `"Next"` button. I put the code `"pos++"` to increase the index whenever the `"Next"` button is clicked, so that each record will show on the `textfield`.

But it only navigates the first 2 records on `textfield`, it stops when I click `"Next"` button again. For the code below, `"..."` means some code is omitted for easy reading purpose.

1. I try to catch the index with `lbpos.Text = pos.ToString();`, the index is up to 1, it is not incremented, I think this is the reason it shows only 2 records on textfield.
2. I use session to retain the state of the choosing records in dataTable `Session["session"] = dt;`, and retrieve it with `dt = (DataTable)Session["session"];`
3. I try to see if datasource has data with

   ```
   if (Session["session"] == null)
       lbsession.Text = "Null";
   ```

   but it seems it is not null because it does not show the string "null".

Code:

```
namespace WebApplication1
{
    public partial class mypage : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        private DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        private SqlDataAdapter adapter;

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        string connString = @"Data Source=DESKTOP- 
 J12F5GP\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=16ThingsDB;Integrated Security=True";

        int pos;

    ...
    protected void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ...
        else if (droplistsearchby.SelectedValue == "Talked")
        {
            string query = "select * from [dbo].[Students] WHERE 
Talked like '%' + @Talked + '%'";
            com.CommandText = query;
            com.Connection = con;
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("Talked", txtsearchby.Text);

            adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(com);
            adapter.Fill(dt);

            GridView1.DataSource = dt;
            Session["session"] = dt;
            GridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
            GridView1.DataBind();

            lbrequestrows.Text = "No of records in this table: " + GridView1.Rows.Count.ToString();
            showData(pos);
            con.Close();
        }
    }

    public void showData(int index)
    {
        txtid.Text = dt.Rows[index][0].ToString();
        txtfirstname.Text = dt.Rows[index][1].ToString();
        txtlastname.Text = dt.Rows[index][2].ToString();
           ...
        txttitle.Text = dt.Rows[index][4].ToString();
        txtdept.Text = dt.Rows[index][5].ToString();
        txtcompany.Text = dt.Rows[index][6].ToString();
    }

    protected void btnNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dt = (DataTable)Session["session"];
        pos++;

        lbpos.Text = pos.ToString();

        if (Session["session"] == null)
            lbsession.Text = "Null";

        lblError.Text = (dt.Rows.Count).ToString();

        if (pos >= dt.Rows.Count)
            pos = 0;

        showData(pos);
    }
}
```

I expect to navigate the records on textfields when button "Next".

Comment: Is this new development? Are you just learning? Web Forms is not a technology you should be learning. It's dying, it's  terrible to work with, and there's much better frameworks out there. You should also ditch the DataTable while you're at it. Just create a class to represent your data.

Comment: I am just learning. Appreciate it! It works! You are amazing.

Answer (score 1):

When an HTTP request comes in, an instance of the Page class is created. When the page is finished processing, an HTTP response is sent to the client and that instance of the page class disappears. When the postback occurs, the a *new* instance of the Page class is created. Thus storing variables in local fields does not make sense in a Page class. You will need to store your state elsewhere.

ViewState, Session, hidden form values on the page, a database. These are all options available for storing application state.

Comment: Thank you very much! You are right!  I created a class for data table and that variable.  Then it works and the variable is not affected when the page is postback.  Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

You can Try by Initializing the pos variable to int pos=0;

Comment: And how would that help?

Comment: Thank you! I tried long time ago, the result was the same.